# Set comprehension VS. For Loop VS. Set Difference

Tags: python, performance, time, set

I am working on a little 3SAT solver written in Python. I am going through a list of lists (called `my_list` in the following examples). I also have a set `checked` that stores the indices of elements in `my_list` that should not be checked when going through the list. Which one of the following do you think would faster?

**Option A)**

```
to_be_checked = {i for i in range(len(my_list)) if i not in checked}
for i in to_be_checked:
    ...
```

**Option B)**

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if i not in checked:
        ...
```

**Option C)**

```
to_be_checked = set(range(len(my_list))) - checked
for i in to_be_checked:
    ...
```

Comment: Did you try timing them?

Comment: @khelwood I did, but results are quite unstable. I'd like to know which one of them is really faster from a design point of view.

Comment: Show us your timing code and your results, so we don't have to repeat the same research.

Answer (score 0):

Option A loops over the dataset once in the dict comprehension and then could possibly loop over that entire amount of data again if nothing was checked so ~O(2n)

Option B loops over the data and on every loop calls 'in' which will loop over all of not_checked so this would be roughly ~O(n^2)

Option C creates a set which implicitly loops over the data, then does a set difference which also loops over the data, and then calls a for loop on that difference so ~O(3n)

I would say A is the fastest but you could potentially make B faster by getting rid of the inner loop from the 'in' operator by using a dictionary.

Realistically you won't notice a difference unless you are using large enough datasets

Answer (score 0):

Option A loops over entire list once and also loops over entire checked list at every iteration due to `if i not in checked` and then loops over the to_be_checked list ~O(3n)

Option B loops over the whole list and then checks `if i not in checked` ~O(2n)

Option C loops over the list once to create the set, then does a difference which is generally O(n) considering no collisions, and then loops over another list. So ~O(3n)